# Capistrano "No Such Host Is Known"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, capistrano

Running capistrano to deploy a rails app to Site5's cloud hosting -- and hitting this error every time:

[image]

The error is to do with Site5 not being able to connect to Github

Does anyone have any information on how to resolve this? I've asked Site5 but figured someone might be able to help on here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the URL which you are using to pull code does not exist. May be a typo.

If you are sure about the error with github. Can you try this.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

You should have your local keys working for you to pull code.